# When I do http request I get error 403 although I enter the correct password and login in postman

Tags: java, spring, web, spring-security, postman

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        UserDetails admin = User.builder()
                .username("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin"))
                .authorities(Role.ADMIN.name())
                .build();
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user"))
                .authorities(Role.USER.name())
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin,user);
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
   @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/**").hasAnyAuthority(Role.ADMIN.name(),Role.USER.name())
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/**").hasAuthority(Role.ADMIN.name())
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        return http.build();

   }


}
```

```
2023-11-14T20:14:07.467+07:00 DEBUG 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-11-14T20:14:07.467+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/11)
2023-11-14T20:14:07.467+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/11)
2023-11-14T20:14:07.467+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/11)
2023-11-14T20:14:07.467+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/11)
2023-11-14T20:14:07.467+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/11)
2023-11-14T20:14:07.467+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/11)
2023-11-14T20:14:07.468+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-11-14T20:14:07.468+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/11)
2023-11-14T20:14:07.468+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2023-11-14T20:14:07.468+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/11)
2023-11-14T20:14:07.468+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/11)
2023-11-14T20:14:07.468+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (10/11)
2023-11-14T20:14:07.468+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (11/11)
2023-11-14T20:14:07.470+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession 6844356C810F91E1262BEAEE54CA1338 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
2023-11-14T20:14:07.470+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-11-14T20:14:07.470+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-11-14T20:14:07.470+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=6844356C810F91E1262BEAEE54CA1338], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-11-14T20:14:07.470+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Did not re-authenticate AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=6844356C810F91E1262BEAEE54CA1338], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] before authorizing
2023-11-14T20:14:07.470+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorizing filter invocation [GET /error] with attributes [hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN','USER')]
2023-11-14T20:14:07.470+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.expression.WebExpressionVoter  : Voted to deny authorization
2023-11-14T20:14:07.471+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /error] with attributes [hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN','USER')] using AffirmativeBased [DecisionVoters=[org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@561953e3], AllowIfAllAbstainDecisions=false]
2023-11-14T20:14:07.472+07:00 TRACE 11932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=6844356C810F91E1262BEAEE54CA1338], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied
```

When I do Http request(post or get) in postman I get 403 error although I enter correct login and password
I already connect Postman Interceptor but It anyway dont work.Without spring security post and get request correctly work. I would appreciate your any help

Comment: You haven't configured any authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

as @M.deinum said, you have to configure an authentication mechanism.
for example configure basic authentication like this:

```
http.httpBasic();
return http.build();
```

after this configuration, you will get 401 error because of csrf for post endpoints.

use this to disable it:

```
http.csrf().disable();
```

see this question for more details :
[Getting 401 Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77426817/why-is-my-authcontroller-returning-me-401-unauthorized-even-though-i-set-all-t)

Comment: I have tried this method , but I get Error"'csrf()' is deprecated and marked for removal".Maybe there is some other method to solve this problem.If you know the method .I be thankful

Comment: finalli i did it'
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
       http
               .authorizeRequests()
               .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
.requestMatchers(antMatcher(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/**")).hasAnyRole(Role.ADMIN.name(),Role.USER.name())
.requestMatchers(antMatcher(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/**")).hasRole(Role.ADMIN.name())
               .anyRequest()
               .authenticated()
               .and()
               .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable()).httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
   }'

Comment: @Alexis yes you'r right. After spring security version 6, we should do it in this way.